# ArcGIS Online: embedded map - zoom to feature

Tags: arcgis-online

I created a webmap for embedded use: [CLICK](https://www.arcgis.com/apps/Embed/index.html?webmap=11b37681acdb444380523c4430934785&feature=speeltoestellen;topdesk;WOLOXCF6836059705).
I want to zoom to a certain point with url parameter.

I followed this for the settings: [ESRI documentation](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/embed-map-parameters.htm). Towards the bottom of the page it says following:

> feature—Allows searching for a specific feature in a searchable feature layer. Find Locations by Layer needs to be set up on the map for a searchable field. The syntax is feature=layerID;searchfield;searchvalue, for example, feature=CentralIndianaCities_634;PLACEFIPS;05860.
>   The following URL references the central Indiana cities example above and can be used to discover the layer ID of the desired layer in your map. Notice id:CentralIndianaCities_634 under operationalLayers. Replace the webmap ID with the ID of your web map to find your layer ID.

I set up the searchable field in the settings (sorry, it's in Dutch). It just says, in the layer "speeltoestellen", the field "topdesk" must contain the parameter
[image: screenshot searchable field]

but for some reason the map doesn't zoom to the selected point. What am I missing to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a solution to the problem. More of a workaround. Using url parameters in a Web Mapping Apllication works. So I created a Web Mapping Application. In the configuration there's a tab called "Search" where i set the layer, field and alias for that field.

And this seems to work.
Not so sure what the difference is between a Web Map and a Web Mapping Application for embedding but it works.

Comment: Web maps are essentially a bounded call to multiple ESRI Equivilant Web Map Services. The find and searchExtent etc, are all capabilities on their services (same with OGC services. A good way to see the difference is that you can open an ArcGIS Online/Portal web map, from inside of ArcGIS Desktop. ....... An ArcGIS Online Web app however, contains more code framework around it, which allows for GUI's, scripts, data access etc etc